# Quartz/CG: Draw a filled path where each line has a different stroke?

Tags: iphone, core-graphics

What's the best practice for drawing a closed, filled path where each line has a different stroke?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Fill the complete path, then [iterate on its elements](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CGPath/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/func/CGPathApply) to stroke one line segment for every `lineto` and `closepath` (see actual Quartz names [here](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CGPath/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/c_ref/CGPathElementType)). Your applier function will need to keep track of the current point itself.

Of course, if any of the elements are `curveto` instead of `lineto`, you may be screwed, but try it anyway.

Comment: i'm screwed, paths contain curveto's :(

Comment: You may not be screwed after all, the more I think about it. You should try it.

Answer (score 1):

Incidentally, if your intent is to make marching ants (a selection marquee), there's a much simpler way: [Set the line dash](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CGContext/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/func/CGContextSetLineDash), then fill and stroke as normal.

Comment: i would like to draw, for example, a red-filled rectangle with the north edge being 10px red, the east one 20px blue, the south one 1px green, and the west one 15px pink. this is just an example. lines may be curves too. (thanks for your answers btw, apprechiated)